# Who is being referred to in 責任を持って送り届けよう?

Tags: meaning

My question here is about whether the speaker is talking about the 戦士たち in this sentence, or perhaps someone not mentioned. One of the reasons I am not sure if he is talking about the 戦士たち is because I wasn't aware if 送り届ける could be used if the object was already on their way to their destination.

A bit of pre context, just right before below extract they used a 冷却剤 to cool the land so that it could be crossed.

> Character 1「これで渡れるようになったのですか？」
>
> 秀穂「さすがに範囲が広いからな。 もうちょっと待ってくれ」
>
> Character 2「ふむ、このまま待つか……」
>
> 猿雷「ここは拙者に任せておけ」
>
> Character 2「うわぁああっ！」
>
> 猿雷「それほどまでに驚く理由が分からん」
>
> Character 1「猿雷さんも応援に来てくれたのですね」
>
> 猿雷「左様、ここが渡れるように成り次第、斥候の役目を果たすつもりだ」
>
> Character 2「ふむ、じゃあ任せて良いか」
>
> 猿雷「任された。お主たちは公爵に報告するが良い」
>
> Character 2「了解だ」
>
> Character 2「秀穂も一緒に来る？」
>
> 秀穂「いや、俺はここで冷却剤の効果を確認しておく」
>
> 猿雷「戦士たちもこちらに向かっているゆえ、責任を持って送り届けよう」

Comment: I'm afraid this piece of context is not enough to answer the question. Could you provide, say, a paragraph before the line?

Comment: @broccoli forest added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from that the fact that Character 2 is going to leave this position to 猿雷, and then 猿雷 lets them go for reporting to 公爵, it is highly probable that this 送り届ける means escorting the team including Character 2 back to some home base or to 公爵.

The subject of the verb, however, is unspecific within this context. It may or may not be some of 戦士 coming on the way, or 猿雷 intended the abstract "we", that is, the faction or group 猿雷 belongs to.

Comment: In the story they part ways with 猿雷 at this point, and meet him again when he has has successfully carried out his recon (斥候) and reports to the 公爵.

Comment: @iceflame Yes, 猿雷 and 秀穂 are apparently excluded from the party going back because they choose to stay at that location.